# How can i copy this cells as this order?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a lot of data and would like to have it like the following example. I have two columns A and B and need to copy A1 in Column C with value B2 in D1 with the rest of column B filled down in column D then repeat

Comment: Do you want to copy the text "A1" or do you want to copy the value from cell A1? Also, your text says "copy ten times", but your sample only has 9 copies. Please edit your question and describe what you REALLY want, so we don't have to guess so much. - Also, please post what you have tried so far and what problems you have run into. What is your code? Or did you use formulas?

Comment: The wrong from me in writing .. the times will not be 10 .. I want to do it with a formula if you can help .. my experience in excel is so simple . I can do it manually but couldn't detect the formula as data is too large than example. So I need help if you can .. thanks

Comment: Doesn't look very difficult at all, possibly just a combination of INDEX, ROW, MOD and QUOTIENT. Your needs are still not very clear though. What is in cell D1? The heading "D", or the value from B2? In other words, are the letters ABCD at the top shown in row 1, or are they column headers? And what happens after the second B10 in your last row? B3 again? B4?

Comment: Sorry if I can't clear more ... In D1 . The value of B2 . And after last row it will be B4 until B10

Comment: @pateksan appreciate if we can share / help others to learn that method.. I tried and I couldn't get the index part to work.. [ I like a non-VBA solution, interested to learn it too.. ] /(^_^)

Comment: @user5520049 Can you try to describe what you are trying to achieve? According to the current edit of your OP, the values of `A10` and `B1` seem to never get used, is that correct/intended?

Comment: @pateksan yes the values of A10 and B1 will not be used

Comment: Please help us help you. Stop us guessing. Mock up the expected result in a spreadsheet and post a screenshot. Then explain the logic. Also, AGAIN: post what you have tried, your code, your formula. This site is not a free script writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think VBA will be your best bet for a solution. Go in Excel to the Developer-tab and select Visual Basic. Develop your macro here on some module.

Try this macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    k = 1
    For j = 1 To 9
        For i = j To 9
            Cells(k, 3) = "=A" & j
            Cells(k, 4) = "=B" & i + 1
            k = k + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want values instead of formulas then replace the two lines with

```
            Cells(k, 3) = Cells(j, 1)
            Cells(k, 4) = Cells(i + 1, 2)
```

Comment: the running take the whole day to implement the code and didn't finish ! as i have 2000 values. where can i see the values that be implemented ? the windows of VBA and excel hanging

Comment: @user5520049 That's odd. The windows of Excel and VBA are usually updated during execution of a macro. One simple way to see how far the macro is, is by pressing the Break button (pause-symbol) or CTRL-Break on the keyboard. By hoovering with your mouse over the variables (e.g. k, j, i) you can see what values they have. Then you should be able to find out the progress of your macro and estimate how long it still takes. Debug your code step by step with F8. It is also possible to turn off [screenupdating](https://www.excely.com/excel-vba/screen-updating.shtml) to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

A no VBA solution :

put

F1 : `=COUNTA(A:A)-1`

G1 : `1`

H1 : `=F1`

and after entering these, drag them downwards..

G2 : `=IF(G1=H1,1,G1+1)`

H2 : `=IF(G2=1,H1-1,H1)`

J1 : `=COUNTIF($G$1:$G1,$G1)`

K1 : `=G1+J1`

M1 : `=COUNTIF($K$1:$K1,$K1)`

O1 : `=INDIRECT("A"&M1,TRUE)`

P1 : `=INDIRECT("B"&K1,TRUE)`

Here is how it look like.. (how the value will be)

[image: The requested info/value/method proving]

Column O & P is the final values (based on column A&B)

The address for indirect in O is 'made' from column M & the column P is from column K.

Column F,G,H,J is used to 'produce' values in column M & K. The logic behind is a bit long to explain.. but you'll get it if you trace how each values (new column) are produced from the previous one.

[ what I whitten before is.. : ]

column O & P is the output. other column 'drives' us through the logic (we can combine it if we want.. separated for clarity purpose).

Idea : find the link between counta(), running row numbers & desired ref location. 'build' the link using indirect().

As per requested/tagged.. an [ excel formula ] solution. ( :

[ which is an simplified explanation and not a line-by-line/basic-function-by-function info which all of us can access the help file to for it. | If there is any special tricks to it.. then I'll say the running countif(). pls comment if anyone didn't get that part. ]

Comment: I take back my recent comments. I'm reluctant to upvote this answer because I can't test it before I understand the OP's actual requirement - see my comment below OP. But this looks very promising. For now, my impression is that, instead of INDIRECT in columns O and P, you could use INDEX, maybe with ROW(), ROW(reference), ROWS(range) or similar.

Comment: thanks for your replying but unfortunately i tried your solution and got wrong data

Comment: As requested in a comment to your question: Edit your question and mock up the desired result. Nobody seems to understand what that actually is. You need to tell us.

Comment: edited & updated. @teylyn thanks for the heads up.. to get what is happening, all are welcomed to ask me via comment. As for the explanation.. I had tried my best to share the logic in my head.. instead of copy-pasting excel documentation.. ( :

Comment: @pateksan thanks for the support, really appreciate it. I tried to figure out o how to use row()/rows() and others.. but couldn't get it to work (before I arrive to this solution). "-_-